# Bootstrap date paginator enable datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepaginator

I use [Bootstrap date paginator](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator). I really can't figure out by myself how to enable datepicker to allow select a date. Calendar is shown but the date selection is disabled.[image]

The initialization code is.

```
var options = {
    selectedDate: $('#selected-date').html(),
    selectedDateFormat: 'YYYYMMDD',
    onSelectedDateChanged: function (event, date) {
        $('#selected-date').html(moment(date).format('YYYYMMDD'));
        disableDatePaginator();
        $('#log-table').DataTable().ajax.reload(function(json){ enableDatePaginator(); });
    },
};
$('#date-paginator').datepaginator(options);
```

I tried `$('#date-paginator').datepaginator(options).datepicker();` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason of the issue. It's necessary to specify valid `startDate` and `endDate` in options for date paginator like this.

```
var options = {
    startDate: moment(new Date(2000, 1, 1)),
    endDate: moment(new Date(2100, 1, 1)),
    selectedDate: $('#selected-date').html(),
    selectedDateFormat: '{{date_format}}',
    onSelectedDateChanged: function (event, date) {
        $('#selected-date').html(moment(date).format('{{date_format}}'));
        disableDatePaginator();
        $('#log-table').DataTable().ajax.reload(function(json){ enableDatePaginator(); });
    },
};
```